# CSS weird layout result

Tags: html, css

I experience some difficulties with sorting out the way to align correctly three of my sliders to the left, setting them one under other. You can see my up do date results...

[image]

I don't understand what causes this because all the sliders are added to a common class and I'm setting them only through it. You can take a look at the css settings here:

```
.slider{
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10%;
    background: url('solid attempt.png');
    width: 300px;
    height: 8px;
    background-size: 300px 8px;
    position: absolute;
    clear: right;
    border-style: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

That's it, in front of each slider should stand a label telling the user what slider associates with, in my case Angle, Speed and Gravity. 
Labels are almost at the top of the page, code, as follows:

```
 .label{
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, if some of you is ready for a chat - even better! I'm looking forward to your answers.
P.S. The blue thing on the right is another  container, if this matters.
:)

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle link?

Comment: Yoou can't use `inline-block`, `float` and `position:absolute` all at the same time...they're mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having seen any of your html code, you may need to add an outside div to each of the sliders and labels. That way you can set the alignment styles to the wrapper and keep them all aligned.

For Example, in your HTML:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
   <label>Slider 1</label>
   <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
<div class="slider-wrapper">
   <label>Slider 2</label>
   <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
<div class="slider-wrapper">
   <label>Slider 3</label>
   <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.slider-wrapper {
    display:block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10%;
    background: url('solid attempt.png');
    width: 300px;
    height: 8px;
    background-size: 300px 8px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slider {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: It worked, yeah, maybe it'd be much better if I'd provided you the html part of all this but the suggestion you've given worked well for me. Now sliders are aligned correctly and I'm ready to go on.  :)

Comment: No problem. Glad to be able to help out.